# Unable to read from s3 through Zeppelin in HDP 2.4 sandbox

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use Zeppelin from HDP 2.4 sandbox but when I try to read an s3 file like

```
   val data = sc.textFile("s3n://...")
   data.take(3)
```

I get an error with the following message:

```
Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found
```

I had set up `fs.s3n.impl` as `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem` and when using hadoop it works.

When I use spark-shell I had to add the aws jars through parameters as `spark-shell --jars /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/*,/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/lib/*`

I tried replicating the configuration with the `%spark` zeppelin interpreter by adding the above paths to `spark.jars` but the result was the same.

What could be the problem?

I am using

- Spark 1.6.0
- Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169
- HDP 2.4 sandbox
- Zeppelin 0.5.5

Comment: have you tried without the n? like `val data = sc.textFile("s3://...")` ??

Comment: Well, I have tried it now but it did not fix it.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884662/why-zeppelin-notebook-is-not-able-to-connect-to-s3?rq=1 out